# Android Service listening on a port

Tags: android, service, server, client

I surfed through a lot of similar questions but didn't get a concrete answer.  I am looking for an Android service code snippet which listens on a port and updates its state when a server on the same network sends something on that port. Also, the client running the android service and the server are on the same network and hence services like GCM cannot be used.

Any inputs?